# removing a multislot variable in JESS

Tags: jess

I have a deftemplate which contains a multislot in JESS and I want to delete a variable in the multilot if the rule is fired. for example:

```
(deftemplate Person (slot name)
                    (multislot friends))
(assert (Person (name John)(friends Jimmy Joe Jessica)))
```

now i want to delete Jimmy from the friends slot.

Thank you very much
Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed some omissions in your question, assuming that the template name is `Person`.

This rule eliminates Jimmy from all `friends` of all Persons.

```
(defrule KillJimmy
    ?p <- (Person (friends $?a Jimmy $?b))
=>
    (modify ?p (friends (create$ $?a $?b)))
)
```

Comment: Hey,Thank you very much Laune, but if I would want to remove more than one from friends, shall I write a seperate rule for each?

Comment: This depends on how you want/have to specify the names, which depends on how and when (compile time, run time) they are known or input, etc.

Comment: can I add the age of each friend in this deftemplate? to for example have (Person (friends (jimmy 33)))??? does this make any sense?

Comment: A Person's age should be stored with a Person. If a friend's age is needed, you'd locate it by looking up that friend's Person fact and get the age from it.

Comment: Is it possible to store the ages of each friend using a bag list? in the case that we just want the ages of the friends? something like ?*Bag*= (bag create Person) (bag set ?*Bag* Fred 22) and do this for all friends? Thank you very much